# Join four tables using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, join

I have 4 tables:

**User**:

- User_id
- List item
- User_Name
- Company_id
- Depart_id
- Group_id

**Company**:

- Company_id
- Company_Name

**Depart**:

- Depart_id
- Depart_Name

**Group**:

- Group_id
- Group_Name

I use Entity Framework, how can I get User information:

- User_id
- User_Name
- Company_Name
- Depart_Name
- Group_Name

Like this:

```
var va = from vx in dbContex.User
         join vy in dbContext.Company
         on vx.CompanyId equals vy.Company_id                     
         into a
         from b in a
         select new {
              vx.User_id,
              vx.User_Name,
              CompanyName = b.Company_Name
         };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
var detailedUserInformations = (from u in dbContext.User
                                join c in dbContext.Company on u.Company_id equals c.Company_id
                                join d in dbContext.Depart on u.Depart_id equals d.Depart_id
                                join g in dbContext.Group on u.Group_id equals d.Group_id
                                select new
                                {
                                    UserId = u.User_id,
                                    UserName = u.User_Name
                                    CompanyName = c.Company_id,
                                    DepartName = d.Depart_Name,
                                    GroupName = g.Group_Name
                                }).ToArray();
```

You have to check if a `.Distinct()` makes sense before you will project (`.ToArray()`) your selection.